# aws kubernetes version update

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I need some help
aws forcing me to update my production cluster 1.21 to 1.22
so, is it safe and what are the pitfalls I may encounter?
If I understood correctly when pressing update button it is going to update only control plane? And if so, can I use with my updated control plane my worker nodes with old workloads (yaml files) ? Or can I update my control plane and create new group with worker nodes and move pods to updated nodes? And how to be with statefulsets, they have pvc and if I move stateful pod to another node how could it find pvc?